# update statement after the condition met in select statement (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

im having trouble with update if selected table is true...

IF this select statement is true

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Add_bonus WHERE value > 0) > 0)
THEN do
UPDATE bonus SET amount = amount + 10 WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement is only allowed in stored procedures, functions, and triggers in MySQL.  You can do this with a single update:

```
UPDATE bonus
    SET amount = amount + 10
    WHERE exists (select 1 from Add_Bonus where value > 0);
```

Note that this query will update *all* rows in the `bonus` table when any appropriate row exists in the `add_bonus` table.  That appears to be the intention of your original query.  More commonly, there might be an employee id linking the two tables.

Also note the use of `exists`.  This is typically more efficient than using `count(*)`, because it can stop processing on the first row that matches.